# Twitter Bootstrap 3 text positioning right after the responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've a question regarding text positioning right after the responsive image.

There is a main background which goes through the whole page.
Then I've a section with background picture. Above(over) it there is a second picture slightly raised up to meet designer's needs:

```
    .first-image {
      position: relative;
      top: -26px;
    }
```

The text goes right after the portrait's area (white circle) and it should be properly positioned:

```
    .image-text-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;

      width: 72%;
      font-size: 0.9vmin;
      transform: translate(-30%, -70%);
    }
```

I'm using the `transform` in order to position text more precisely, but is it excess?

Am I right in this approach ? Or it should be done in another way and this markup is completely wrong?

Another heard idea is that the text could be positioned inside the image and then the whole div streched to full width...
So such big picture could be shrank till the portrait and further area strethed with CSS in order to optimize the bandwidth. Or this approach is a deadlock?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19264/

IMG mockup: [image]

Comment: can you post an image how to do want the page looks like.

Comment: Here it is: http://i79.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0413/1c/0e62ea56e824d4f62a0f84bb9e78751c.jpg

Comment: Hi Kuzma, Sorry to say that currently i am in office and here most of the image upload sites are block by firewall..i will check that after i reached home..otherwise you can edit your question and add image there itself through stackoverflow image upload.

Comment: Hi Satya, just uploaded